# Android Studio crashes when clicking color on Vector Assets after update

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I updated Android Studio to

Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-62-lowlatency

but after update, every time I want to add Vector Assets and change the color by clicking the color makes Android Studio aborted. Below is the log showed in Terminal:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe7412adc69, pid=10301, tid=0x00007fe6f6e2b700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_202) (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b49-5587405 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libawt_xawt.so+0x46c69]  ReadRegionsInList.constprop.5+0x3d9
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/fsevenm/core or core.10301
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/fsevenm/java_error_in_STUDIO_10301.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

[image: Android Studio crashes when clicking color on Vector Assets after update]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Studio.

This has been raised as an issue: 
 ("Android Studio suddenly close without any warning when try to change color in Vector Asset or Image Asset"), see [issuetracker 138910326](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138910326)

You can add your experience to the issue.

You can change the color manually (in a text editor) until it is fixed.

see also [issuetracker 140642034](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140642034), [132316444](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132316444), [67980679](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67980679), [37061710](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37061710)

Answer (score 1):

[See the Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEsHQ.png)    I don't know why, but if you start the Gnome session over xorg the problem don't happens.

I have been using that option to avoid the crash

Comment: Did you mean Wayland session over Xorg?

Comment: fsevenm, see the attached picture. Hope this helps. Thanks!